# How can I convert this sql statement to linq expression

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

How can I convert this sql query to linq expression, I'm new in linq and searched this but I could not understand how to convert it.

```
SELECT 
   a.afiliacaoid,
   DATE_FORMAT(a.horario, '%d/%m/%Y') data,
   COUNT(a.afiliacaoid) acessos,
   IFNULL(p.pedidos,0) pedidos
FROM 
   acesso a LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT p.afiliacaoid, 
           DATE_FORMAT(p.cadastro , '%d/%m/%Y') data, 
           COUNT(p.afiliacaoid) pedidos 
           FROM pedido p) p ON a.afiliacaoid = p.afiliacaoid 
               AND DATE_FORMAT(a.horario, '%d/%m/%Y') = data
WHERE 
   a.afiliacaoid=1
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.horario, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I would suggest you map the classes so there is a navigational property from acesso to pedido, so that you can write something like a.pedio.Id.Count();

Comment: Possible OT: does the query above work at all? With the COUNT aggregation in subquery without GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this tool to convert: https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tool that might be helpful to you - http://www.sqltolinq.com